# Mic and Headphone jack into one?

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone

I recently bought a new headphones, which have two jacks; One for microphone and one for headphones.
My Macbook Air only has one "hole", which is for the entire headset. I bought a reduction.
The problem is, neither my Mac nor other computers recognize the external microphone I have wired up through the reduction, not even if I plug the microphone jack itself to the headset hole. (Headphones play sound even if its wired thru the reduction, so the reduction itself is not broken anyway.)
I've tried it on several computers and systems, but I'm writing this here because I have a Mac after all.

Hope you can tell me some info on that problem, thanks.

Comment: Does it work on other computers?

Comment: No, it's totally the same as on my Mac. Can't detect external microphone.

Comment: So it's either the reduction adaptor or the headphone itself which has a problem.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the reduction adaptor that's bad. You may have gotten one that's only for output sound and not microphone, since you mentioned that's working on other computers.

Comment: Im not so educated in this field, but the end of the adapter has 3 stripes, instead of just 2, so i think it's for the mic too, as the shop assistant handed me this one specially when selecting the headphones.

Comment: Did I see from that rather confused explanation that you swapped the plugs over at one point, mic into headphone socket? That won't do it a bit of good.

Comment: No, i think i explained it weird way. I plugged everything as it should be, problem is that all computers act the same way and they don't recognize external mic being connected.

Comment: You need one of these https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B004SP0WAQ/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?qid=1450995915&sr=8-1&pi=SY200_QL40&keywords=headset+microphone+adapter&dpPl=1&dpID=41WCy3b0sCL&ref=plSrch Note: it's not the same thing as a y-adapter, it's specifically made for 2 plug headsets to single hole audio.

Comment: Okay, nice to know. Thank you for the recommendation.